# Alternatives to static methods in a framework PHP

Tags: php, class, coding-style

Lately I have been trying to create my own PHP framework, just to learn from it (As we may look into some bigger and more robust framework for production). One design concept I currently have, is that most core classes mainly work on static functions within classes.

Now a few days ago, I've seen a few articles about "Static methods are death to testability". This concerned me as.. yeah.. my classes contain mostly static methods.. The main reason I was using static methods is that a lot of classes would never need more than one instance, and static methods are easy to approach in the global scope. Now I'm aware that static methods aren't actually the best way to do things, I'm looking for a better alternative.

Imagine the following code to get a config item:

```
$testcfg = Config::get("test"); // Gets config from "test"
echo $testcfg->foo; // Would output what "foo" contains ofcourse.

/*
 * We cache the newly created instance of the "test" config,
 * so if we need to use it again anywhere in the application,
 * the Config::get() method simply returns that instance.
 */
```

This is an example of what I currently have. But according to some articles, this is bad. 
Now, I could do this the way how, for example, CodeIgniter does this, using:

```
$testcfg = $this->config->get("test");
echo $testcfg->foo;
```

Personally, I find this harder to read. That's why I would prefer another way.

**So in short**, I guess I need a better approach to my classes. I would not want more than one instance to the config class, maintain readability and have easy access to the class. Any ideas?

Note that I'm looking for some best practice or something including a code sample, not some random ideas. Also, if I'm bound to a $this->class->method style pattern, then would I implement this efficiently?

Comment: Remi: @Elias said it all in his answer, but for your ->get() part... have you considered implementing the `ArrayAccess` interface, which would then allow you to use your class as if it was an array?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, actually not. I've read a little about it a few days ago but I guess I should see and try how it works. If you could give me a quick summary of it, what exactly does it do?

Comment: @Remi-X: Pretty easy: `class Foo implements ArrayAccess`, and [read the docs of the interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). Everything _listed_ in the interface must be implemented in the class, and you're good to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to Sébastien Renauld's comments: [here's an article on Dependency Injection (DI) and Inversion of Control (IoC)](http://phpmaster.com/inversion-of-control-the-hollywood-principle/) with some examples, and a few extra words on the Hollywood principle (quite important when working on a framework).

Saying your classes won't ever need more than a single instance doesn't mean that statics are a must. Far from it, actually. If you browse this site, and read through PHP questions that deal with the singleton *"pattern"*, you'll soon find out why singletons are a bit of a no-no.

I won't go into the details, but testing and singletons don't mix. Dependency injection is definitely worth a closer look. I'll leave it at that for now.

To answer your question:
Your exaple (`Config::get('test')`) implies you have a static property in the `Config` class somewhere. Now if you've done this, as you say, to facilitate access to given data, imagine what a nightmare it would be to debug *your* code, if that value were to change somewhere... It's a static, so change it once, and it's changed everywhere. Finding out where it was changed might be harder than you anticipated. Even so, that's *nothing* compared to the issues someone who *uses* your code will have in the same situation.
And yet, the *real* problems will only start when that person using your code wants to test whatever it is he/she made: If you want to have access to an instance in a given object, that has been instantiated in some class, there are plenty of ways to do so (especially in a framework):

```
class Application
{//base class of your framework
    private $defaulDB = null;
    public $env = null;
    public function __construct($env = 'test')
    {
        $this->env = $env;
    }
    private function connectDB(PDO $connection = null)
    {
        if ($connection === null)
        {
            $connection = new PDO();//you know the deal...
        }
        $this->defaultDB = $connection;
    }
    public function getDB(PDO $conn = null)
    {//get connection
        if ($this->defaultDB === null)
        {
            $this->connectDB($conn);
        }
        return $this->defaultDB;
    }
    public function registerController(MyConstroller $controller)
    {//<== magic!
         $controller->registerApplication($this);
         return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Application` class has a method that passes the `Application` instance to your controller, or whatever part of your framework you want to grant access to scope of the `Application` class.
Note that I've declared the `defaultDB` property as a private property, so I'm using a getter. I can, if I wanted to, pass a connection to that getter. There's a lot more you can do with that connection, of course, but I can't be bothered writing a full framework to show you everything you can do here :).

Basically, all your controllers will extend the `MyController` class, which *could* be an abstract class that looks like this:

```
abstract class MyController
{
    private $app = null;
    protected $db = null;
    public function __construct(Application $app = null)
    {
        if ($app !== null)
        {
            return $this->registerApplication($app);
        }
    }
    public function registerApplication(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getApplication()
    {
        return $this->app;
    }
}
```

So in your code, you can easily do something along the lines of:

```
$controller = new MyController($this);//assuming the instance is created in the Application class
$controller = new MyController();
$controller->registerApplication($appInstance);
```

In both cases, you can get that single DB instance like so:

```
$controller->getApplication()->getDB();
```

You can test your framework with easily by passing a different DB connection to the `getDB` method, if the `defaultDB` property hasn't been set in this case. With some extra work you can register multiple DB connections at the same time and access those at will, too:

```
$controller->getApplication->getDB(new PDO());//pass test connection here...
```

This is, by no means, the full explanation, but I wanted to get this answer in quite quickly before you end up with a huge static (and thus useless) codebase.

*In response to comments from OP:*

On how I'd tackle the `Config` class. Honestly, I'd pretty much do the same thing as I'd do with the `defaultDB` property as shown above. But I'd probably allow for more targeted control on what class gets access to what part of the config:

```
class Application
{
    private $config = null;
    public function __construct($env = 'test', $config = null)
    {//get default config path or use path passed as argument
        $this->config = new Config(parse_ini_file($config));
    }
    public function registerController(MyController $controller)
    {
        $controller->setApplication($this);
    }
    public function registerDB(MyDB $wrapper, $connect = true)
    {//assume MyDB is a wrapper class, that gets the connection data from the config
        $wrapper->setConfig(new Config($this->config->getSection('DB')));
        $this->defaultDB = $wrapper;
        return $this;
    }
}

class MyController
{
    private $app = null;
    public function getApplication()
    {
        return $this->app;
    }
    public function setApplication(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        return $this;
    }
    //Optional:
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->app->getConfig();
    }
    public function getDB()
    {
        return $this->app->getDB();
    }
}
```

Those last two methods aren't really required, you could just as well write something like:

```
$controller->getApplication()->getConfig();
```

Again, this snippet is all a bit messy and incomplete, but it does go to show you that you can *"expose"* certain properties of one class, by passing a reference to that class to another. Even if the properties are private, you can use getters to access them all the same. You can also use various register-methods to control what it is the registered object is allowed to see, as I've done with the DB-wrapper in my snippet. A DB class shouldn't deal with viewscripts and namespaces, or autoloaders. That's why I'm only registering the DB section of the config.

Basically, a lot of your main components will end up sharing a number of methods. In other words, they'll end up implementing a given interface. For each main component (assuming the classic MVC pattern), you'll have one abstract base-class, and an inheritance chain of 1 or 2 levels of child classes: `Abstract Controller` > `DefaultController` > `ProjectSpecificController`.
At the same time, all of these classes will probably expect another instance to be passed to them when constructed. Just look at the `index.php` of any ZendFW project:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV);
$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

That's all you can see, but inside the application, all other classes are being instantiated. That's why you can access neigh on everything from anywhere: all classes have been instantiated inside another class along these lines:

```
public function initController(Request $request)
{
    $this->currentController = $request->getController();
    $this->currentController = new $this->currentController($this);
    return $this->currentController->init($request)
                                   ->{$request->getAction().'Action'}();
}
```

By passing `$this` to the constructor of a controller class, that class can use various getters and setters to get to whatever it needs... Look at the examples above, it could use `getDB`, or `getConfig` and use that data if that's what it needs.
That's how most frameworks I've tinkered or worked with function: The application is kicks into action and determines what needs to be done. That's the Hollywood-principle, or Inversion of Control: the Application is started, and the application determines what classes it needs when. In the link I provided I believe this is compared to a store creating its own customers: the store is built, and decides what it wants to sell. In order to sell it, it will create the clients it wants, and provide them with the means they need to purchase the goods...

And, before I forget: Yes, all this can be done without a single static variable, let alone function, coming into play. I've built my own framework, and I've never felt there was no other way than to *"go static"*. I did use the Factory pattern at first, but ditched it pretty quickly. 
IMHO, a good framework is modular: you should be able to use bits of it (like Symfony's components), without issues. Using the Factory pattern makes you *assume* too much. You *assume* class X will be available, which isn't a given.
Registering those classes that are available makes for far more portable components. Consider this:

```
class AssumeFactory
{
    private $db = null;
    public function getDB(PDO $db = null)
    {
        if ($db === null)
        {
            $config = Factory::getConfig();//assumes Config class
            $db = new PDO($config->getDBString());
        }
        $this->db = $db;
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
class RegisteredApplication
{//assume this is registered to current Application
    public function getDB(PDO $fallback = null, $setToApplication = false)
    {
        if ($this->getApplication()->getDB() === null)
        {//defensive
            if ($setToApplication === true && $fallback !== null)
            {
                $this->getApplication()->setDB($fallback);
                return $fallback;//this is current connection
            }
            if ($fallback === null && $this->getApplication()->getConfig() !== null)
            {//if DB is not set @app, check config:
                $fallback = $this->getApplication()->getConfig()->getSection('DB');
                $fallback = new PDO($fallback->connString, $fallback->user, $fallback->pass);
                return $fallback;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException('No DB connection set @app, no fallback');
        }
        if ($setToApplication === true && $fallback !== null)
        {
            $this->getApplication()->setDB($fallback);
        }
        return $this->getApplication()->getDB();
    }
}
```

Though the latter version is slightly more work to write, it's quite clear which of the two is the better bet. The first version just assumes too much, and doesn't allow for safety-nets. It's also quite dictatorial: suppose I've written a test, and I need the results to go to another DB. I therefore need to change the DB connection, for the entire application (user input, errors, stats... they're all likely to be stored in a DB).
For those two reasons alone, the second snippet is the better candidate: I can pass another DB connection, that overwrites the application default, or, if I don't want to do that, I can either use the default connection, or attempt to create the default connection. Store the connection I just made, or not... the choice is entirely mine. If nothing works, I just get a `RuntimeException` thrown at me, but that's not the point.

Comment: This deserves more +1. Might be worth mentioning IoC along with DI, to simplify testing while still possibly allowing singleton-esque approaches.

Comment: Awesome answer. Could you just clarify one thing in your answer? I got a slight idea of how I would inject my own class into the controller (so being able to do `$this->class->method()`), but I would like to see yours too. Also, as you state you wanted to get the answer in quickly, I would love seeing the things you left out now :P

Comment: @Remi-X: I wouldn't _inject_ my object into a controller class, I'd extend the framework's controller class, and use that as my controller. AFAIK, that's how most frameworks work. That way, you'd only have to do `$this->method()` where `$this` is `class MyCustomController extends MyController`. If you pass that object to a method or function that uses typehinting, it'll accept the object as an instance of `MyController`, as well as an instance of `MyCustomController`

Comment: @Remi-X: Things I've left out are `namespace`, Inversion of Control, automated testing and Dependency Injection, and some more elaborate code examples. All of the things I can tell you about this have all been written about on the net, with tons of examples. Don't take this the wrong way, but please, google the afore mentioned terms

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I actually meant a class like the config class, not the extension on the base controller. And ofcourse I've googled around. It just sounded like you had some more to tell, but left it out at the moment of writing to get the answer more quickly done.

Comment: @Remi-X: I'll post a more elaborate example of what I'd do with the `Config` class

Comment: @Remi-X: Ok, that took longer than I expected... partly because I'm tired and I don't know what I'm writing... it could well be that I've just rambled on and on without answering your question. Ah, well... If you don't mind, I'm going to be a little rep-whore and ask you to accept my answer, since you said it was _"awsome"_? ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) would help you: see the examples about `__get()` and `__set()`

You should also take a look at [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php): it may help you to get rid of some classes with static methods only.

Comment: Do you have any idea how inefficient those magic methods are?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld well, it's a feature, not a hack. Therefore I expect the efficiency to be fair and improving in time.

Comment: @JanTuroň: Though some things might improve, they'll never beat common sense. You can add properties to objects on-the-fly, but that requires reallocating memory for each instance. No matter how you look at it, it'll slow you down. Same thing goes for magic methods: perform a lookup on the instance, then call a method (which calls other functions or loops x times) and return some data... it's just additional overhead, brought along by lazy programming

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: the only valid use of magic methods is `__wakeup`. That's the only one that is not re-writable in userland code.

Comment: @JanTuroň: Never said it was a hack. Do you still have any idea how inefficient it is? You look up the property in the hash table, it doesn't exist, *then* you call the magic method? That's two unnecessary steps per call.

Comment: You talk about the magic methods as if they are antipattern. I'm also a big fan of efficiency, but I think we should use native features of particular language instead of looking at them from the perspective of another language. I believe it is PHP's way how to deal with automatic properties. But you may see the PHP as an intermediary language between C++ and people who don't understand low-level programming too much. I agree, but it is not an issue for people using PHP.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Fair enough, although `__invoke` can't really be recreated as such, but is just _terrible_ coding style. I like PHP, sadly it takes a lot of abuse, which brings with it a lot of terrible code...

Comment: @JanTuroň: I get where you're coming from. But as you can probably tell from my latest comment: I'm a bit of a sucker when it comes to good coding standards. The more I understand the ZendEngine, the more I've come to realize how much tools PHP gives to its users to abuse the language... IMHO, more people _should_ know about the weak-spots of PHP. That way, they'd probably curse because they have to write a bit more code, but in the long run, the language would benefit (certain iffy features could be deprecated - in an ideal world, that is)

Comment: @JanTuroň: I use the methods native to PHP. However, some of them encourage something called **slacking**. Using `_call`, for example, implies that you do not know the interface exposed by your class. That's not a feature - that's a bug sitting in the chair in front of the computer, and I know very few other languages that allow you to go with something like that. Because it exists doesn't mean it should be used. There are cases where `__call` is handy, but they're few and (very) far between.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Never ever felt the need to use that one.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Ditto, and I fully subscribe you your latest comment, too. Magic methods aren't a hack as such, but I referred to them as _tools offered by the language (PHP), that enable you to abuse that very same language_. They're indeed encouraging nasty habits, bad programming and general ignorance. People who write PHP often have a hard time learning even slightly more stringent languages.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld +1 looks like PHP creators don't do great job every time. Maybe I should have given an answer *Some PHP features really sucks, you should use some macho language*...

Comment: @JanTuroň: in case you want another example of a PHP "feature" that is most of the time used to do something that shouldn't be done, look at `eval()`. Not thread-safe, with no way to catch fatals, and cannot be limited in scope. There's Runkit, which is thread-safe, but eval is just so much easier to use... and so much harder to debug as it breaks the callback stack, too!

Comment: @JanTuroň: it's not about macho/not macho, it's about "if you don't know what your class has in terms of methods and cannot bind an interface to it, you're doing it wrong". And even if you have the scenario of a dir lookup class, that's when you use a normal function to do the calling (`method_exists` is relatively - ish - efficient)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld and that's exactly what I mean by *macho*. Of course there are cross-language often misused features: `eval` or `goto`, whatever. I agree with you that `__call()` is not the most efficient feature in the world, I just tried to answer from the perspective of PHP, knowing that efficiency is not its cutie mark.

Comment: @JanTuroň: It's not macho - your reasoning is flawed. It's not because PHP is slow (hint: all interpreted languages are) that it gives you the magical incentive to *make it slow**er***. There is nothing *macho* about saying "This version takes 3 extra lookups to do the same thing" - it's called performance analysis. If that reasoning was correct, I'd slack very hard in C too, as it's slower than ASM, which itself is slower than machine code. What is that kind of reasoning?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Please, let it go. You've made your point (he +1-ed your comment about the `__call` method after all). Perhaps you don't intend to, but your comments, when you put them all together, do look a bit like a rant. We're all in agreement that some things about PHP aren't all that good, no reason to argue. Except of course: PHP isn't really an interpreted language as such: since PHP5 it's compiled to byte-code, much like Java is... :-P

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: You're right. Thanks for the comment (though I wasn't about the +1). Also, you know what I meant by interpreted :-P the conversion happens, even just once if APC is on.